# For duplicate questions, provide a direct link to the root duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I posted [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280245/321521) detailing my walk down a lengthy linked list of duplicates to finally find my Russian doll of an answer.

It would have been so convenient to have had a [Table of Duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36366/321521), so I could have easily seen at a glance what different variations might be. A summary of top-voted ones would be especially useful considering [there's no limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280249/321521) to how many there could be in a linked chain. I upvoted that feature-request, but since it's from 2010 it's probably just not worth it to implement. It was even stirred up again in 2013 with the [Duplicate Questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183490/321521), on which [Shog9 said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183490/duplicate-questions-sidebar#comment560042_183490):

> Duplicates should be a subset of "linked" questions. This isn't entirely true at the moment, but will be shortly.

Shortly can take a while in my experience, and I'm sure this is implemented to some extent already. But neither Shog's comment nor [Jeff Atwood's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47807/321521) were fully satisfying the feature request. At any rate, I think that everyone agrees it's a good idea.

So I propose a small deliverable starting point that will likely only be progress toward both of these proposals. And that is to just provide a direct link to the ***root*** duplicate question (the question that is not marked as a duplicate) on a closed duplicate question. It doesn't even have to muddle the sidebar, just a link below the closed message.